# Rolify scope roles to many objects and different classes Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rolify

I am trying to "extend" Rolify functionality to have some global roles such as 'Admin', 'Member', 'Guest', etc... and to be able to set up different "scopes" for each user who have a specific role.

For example, in my app i have this `admin` role, which is a "super role" meaning it grants access to basically everything. But i also want to be able to "scope" this role for another User, the scope will be, for example  'he will have access to all users, but only if they are from countries A, B, C and from cities X, Y, Z'. I know rolify supports different roles with different scopes, but what i want is to manage "global roles" with different scopes only for different users.

I thought about doing something like a 'Scope' model that belongs to a Role and to a User, in which i would have HABTM relationships with countries and cities, and then use that for authorization (I'm using CanCanCan). But i ran into many issues when working on this approach. It was something like:

```
class Scope
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role

  has_and_belongs_to_many :countries
  has_and_belongs_to_many :cities
end
```

One of the issues i ran into was that i need to grant the role at the same time i create a scope, and if a user is 'revoked' of a role, the scope which belongs to the user and the role, needs to be destroyed. This last part i found particularly hard since 'Scope' is not related to 'users_roles' table.

Anyone has any idea on a better approach to this problem? I'm having a hard time figuring out the right way to have a role that has custom scopes for each user (basically i need something in the middle of the user and the role to define what is the user's scope with that role).

Appreciate any help I can get!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create something of your own `has_and_belongs_to_many` is not the answer (hint: [it's almost never the right answer](https://flatironschool.com/blog/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many/)). Using [HABTM is the akilles heel of Rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/pull/181) as its assocations look like this:

```
class User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
end

class Role
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  belongs_to :resource, 
    polymorphic: true,
    optional: true
end
```

This doesn't let you you query the users_roles table directly or add additional columns or logic. Fixing it has been an open issue since 2013. There are workarounds but Rolify may not be the right tool for the job here anyways.

If you want to roll your own you want to use `has_many through:` to setup an actual join model so you can query the join table directly and add assocations, additional columns and logic to it.

```
class User
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :roles, through: :user_roles
end

class UserRole
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role 
  belongs_to :resource, 
    polymorphic: true,
    optional: true
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id,
    scope: [:role_id, :resource_id, :resource_type]
end

class Role
  validates :name, presence: true, 
                   uniqueness: true
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :roles, through: :user_roles
end
```

This moves the resource scoping from being per role to being per user.

While you could add additional join tables between the `user_roles` table and the "scoped" resources its not strictly necissary unless you want to avoid polymorphic asssocations.

Comment: Side note: For any kind of authorization thats even slightly complex you want to get rid of CanCanCan and switch to Pundit. The single Ability class and its DSL just turns into a total mess and gets in your way. Its a relic from a bygone era when people were inventing DSLs for everything.

Comment: Hey @max thank you for your input. Your take on how to solve this problem is actually what i too believe to be the right way to do it, but the thing is i can't really replace rolify as of right now. So i have to come up with something using what i got. Do you think i could "migrate" Rolify's HABTM to HMT succesfully without "breaking" it's functionality? That way i could follow this approach, taking advantage of my 'users_roles' table. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: There a mutiple workarounds to change Rolify to a `has_many through:` assocation [listed on this issue](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/issues/318). But you'll be fighting the way the library was designed as it expect the scoping to be on the roles table which will break `has_role?` and all the DB scoping methods.

Comment: You can kind of do what you want with rolify by adding a role for every name/resource combo and granting users those roles.

Comment: Yeah so i will basically have 'X' quantity of 'admin' roles, each with a different combo of resources for cities, countries, etc... Sounds ugly, especially on my serializer, but it serves my purpose. Thank you for your help Max. I'll probably go with that solution. I guess i can mark this as solved.